# Facbook Social login app throws error with code : 191

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, facebook, social

I have configure Facebook Social login app In Magento. But when i click to authorize and Get login, it's give me a following error.

[image]

Can any one help me ?

Comment: did you create the coresponding facebook app?

Comment: Yes, I have created app in developer.facbook.com. Do you have any guide to create facbook app, because facbook did change in app creation process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your domain to the facebook app. Go to Facebook App dashboard: **Settings > Advanced > Domain Manager > Add a Domain.**

Comment: Thank you for your Response, I have tried this http://prntscr.com/iulxpq but still getting same error. let me know if anything wrong in my screenshot.

Comment: Any idea about this error https://snipboard.io/XsWa8w.jpg thanks @Adrian Z.